# Send Discord bot message when API function called

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'd like to send a message from a Discord bot whenever an API endpoint gets triggered.

It seems the only way to send messages is in response to discord events, for example using

```
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
```

I'd appreciate any pointers on how to send a discord bot message that's not triggered by an async Discord event (using discord.py preferably)

Thanks!

Comment: What API trigger are you looking for?

Comment: I want to expose an API so that I can call for example /greet and have my bot send the message when the API gets called.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but if I were you I would stick with events. They're pre-coded and much easier to use than the raw API.

Comment: suppose I want to send a message in discord when someone buys something on my website - how do I do that with events?

Comment: @alxcnwy were you able to come up with any solution? I am kinda trying to achieve the same